# Perl - TAP::Harness and test_args

Tags: perl, unit-testing, testing

I am using [TAP::Harness](http://search.cpan.org/~andya/Test-Harness-3.23/lib/TAP/Harness.pm) in perl like this:

```
$harness = TAP::Harness->new({
        formatter_class => 'TAP::Formatter::Console',
        merge => 1,
        verbosity => 1,
        normalize => 1,
        color => 1,
        test_args => ['--url', $url, '--session', $session],
    });
```

Sometime later I call $harness->runtests(), passing an array of several tests.

Problem is, in all of my tests:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@ARGV;
```

Outputs:

```
$VAR1 = [];
```

Does test_args not come out in @ARGV in the underlying tests?  I need to pass some options through to each test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your initialization work? I had to pass hashref to the constuctor to make it work:

```
use TAP::Harness;

$harness = TAP::Harness->new({
    formatter_class => 'TAP::Formatter::Console',
    merge           => 1,
    verbosity       => 1,
    normalize       => 1,
    color           => 1,
    test_args       => ['--url', $url, '--session', $session],
});

$harness->runtests('simple.t');
```

In the test `simple.t`:

```
use Test::More;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

dump [@ARGV];    # prints ["--url", "", "--session", ""]

done_testing;
```

Comment: I retyped some of the code, b/c I dynamically fill out the hash that's passed in, so that's a typo.  Strange that you can get it to work though, I'm going to copy your code and try it.

Comment: @Jonathan.Peppers - please note the difference between passing hash (as list) and hash reference. The `{}` within the `new` call is constructing it. But anyway thanks for pointing me to `TAP::Harness`.

Comment: @Jonathan.Peppers - does my sample work for you? Btw, I am using perl 5.12.2 on WinXP and `Test-Harness` version 3.23

Comment: I'm not sure what I was doing wrong, your example works.  I have already moved on to saving these settings to a file for other reasons (I need these settings to persist), so I don't have my original code to try.  Marking you as the answer though, thanks for the help.